# Boolean modifier creates inaccurate vertices which I don't want

Tags: modifiers, vertices, mirror

[image]
I have this geometrical wirelike shape which I want to duplicate, mirror and merge at the middle and have one solid object that doesn't have any faces inside it eventually.
[image]
After I modeled the shape, I duplicated, mirrored it and made two sides intersect.Then I realized some corners doesn't fit properly ,so I replaced the vertices with snapping to vertices option on and made them overlap at the intersection points.
[image]
Then I went to the Boolean modifier and used union to merge them and have no face inside ,but unfortunately when I applied it I noticed there are some extra vertices at the points of intersection.
[image]
Furthermore I grabbed the extra vertex and saw that there are another one under that too, I really couldn't figure out why I have this problem.
[image]
[image]
I searched all over internet for any information but nothing really helped me to sort out the situation. I guess it's something to do with replacing and overlapping the vertices before the Boolean , but I really don't know how to fix it. Any help or idea of another way to do what I want will be really helpful! thank you !

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: In this particular workflow what you want is to use a mirror modifier and enable "Bisect" along X

Comment: @Gorgious thank you so much , it was a pain for two days, but what you told me to do is exactly what I needed.